# How do you activate the Grandmapocalypse?

Tags: cookie-clicker

How do I activate the Grandmapocalypse in *[Cookie Clicker](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger the Grandmapocalypse by purchasing the "One Mind" upgrade from the Research Facility.

If you don't have a Research facility yet you can unlock it by having the "elder achievement" (have at least 7 different grandmas).

Once you have the research facility you will have to keep buying the upgrades that it unlocks until the "one mind" upgrade becomes available, which should be the 6th one. Each upgrade takes about 30 minutes to research and become available. Note that you need to purchase an upgrade before the next upgrade begins researching.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have 15 farms, mines, factories, banks, temples, wizard towers, and shipments each, first, and buy the corresponding grandma-related upgrade, such as “Miner grandmas” or “Cosmic grandmas” and then you have access to the Bingo Center/Research Facility upgrade, taking you through 4 other research/facility upgrades and then the “One Mind” upgrade, and that starts the grandmapocalypse․ The catch is that Bingo Center/Research Facility upgrade is 1 quadrillion cookies, and the cost doubles for each further upgrade you go into, capping at 32 quadrillion for One Mind. (It keeps growing for the 4 that come after, though, including Communal Brainsweep and Elder Pact). Find out more at https://cookieclicker.fandom.com/wiki/Cookie_Clicker_Wiki

Answer (score -4):

Another way to activate it is to first make Grandma hate you. And to do that you just need to make enough cookies and then she'll start saying things like, "It begins", or "We rise". When she starts saying that, you know it is getting close to Grandmapocalypse.

If you sell a Grandma, it gives you an achievement. "Sell a Grandma" and on the bottom right corner it says, "I  thought you loved me", and then you will see messages from grandma saying,"It thought it could get rid of us, the nasty little thing.", or "It thought we would go away by selling us, how quaint.".

Comment: Please ensure that your answers are factually correct before posting them.

Comment: ...Well they're not exactly my answers. I found them on a different website and it said that's how you do it soo... Yeah.

Comment: And also on my last ascension, I only got 10 Heavenly Chips and I never got the research facility; but I did get evil Grandmas.

Comment: But I still don't know know when or how Wrinklers come in.

Comment: And by the way; have you ever  seen the comment on cookie clicker;"Is our planet getting lighter?'' in the game? If so it makes no sense, because there's still the same amount of mass and weight on the planet.